# Synchronizing between MS Access Database and MySql

Tags: ms-access

My company has an MS Access Database on a local machine and a MySQL Database on the server maintained by phpMyAdmin. What they've asked me to do is to push any changes from the MS Access database to the MySQL Database.

My plan to solve this problem is:
1. Check for changes(creations,updates,deltetions) in the MS Access Database after a fixed interval.
2. If a change exists, get the new records,encode them in JSON/XML
3. Upload changes to server and update the database

I've never worked with MS Access Databases before so what I'd like to know is, how can I find out what changes have been made to an MS Access Database. I want to know the field names and the values for each record.

Thanks.

Comment: I was hired to do something similar at one time. The level of effort, jankiness of having an intermediary script, and delay of data transfer were the reasons i gave to do away with access entirely, and so we converted everything to MySQL and built a web interface to interact with the data. Your situation may be different, but i would consider this as a very good alternative. What if that local machine dies? What if the local machine network goes down?

Comment: Why not just adding the MySql tales as linked tables in Access ? All you need is the MySql ODBC driver. This way you can skip the JSON/XML part.

Comment: @iDevelop What if the local machines network goes down? Will there be gaps in data?

Comment: @LeeSalminen: proposed the same points to the company but it seems they've been relying on MS Access from the very start and it's too late to change.

Comment: @iDevlop: is it possible to link MySQL to an exisitng Access Database. If you could link me to any documentation/guide about this, that would be a big help!

Comment: @W.K.S Ugh, I hate companies that are adverse to change. Best of luck to you! I've used the foreign key column that stores the primary key of an access record method before and it works decently. Don't know about linking a remote MySQL to Access, but you'll probably still need a script in the event that the Access database can't connect to the internet/intranet.

Comment: @LeeSalminen you can still have linked tables and have the network go down. You just also have local tables. then all the syncing is done in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your MySQL tables, I would keep a foreign key column that matches the primary key on the Access tables.

Then you just need to write a comparison script to delete from MySQL when that key no longer exists in Access etc...

See my comment under your question though. It may (usually) makes more sense in the long term to do away with access entirely. I've convinced clients to do this before and they never regretted it. Just come up with a good SWOT analysis...business people love those.

Comment: +1 because I absolutely agree with you on the `Ditch-Access` point :) Thanks for the idea but it only handles deletions. I'm looking for something that handles edits as well. My idea so far is to add a field containing a hashcode of each record. I use a script to check changes in hashcodes to find changes in the db but i was hoping that Access' feature set would offer a simpler solution